# R: using hist() to get a frequency for a df of dates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `dates` which only has one column labelled `year-month` which contains many dates, in date format, a sample of which is as follows:

`2012-Feb`
`2013-Dec`
`2012-Sep`

I am trying to get a histogram plot using hist() to plot the counts for each particular date in the dataframe. For example, the total count for `2012-Feb` is 500.

When I run `hist(dates, xlab = "Year-Month")` I get an error that says: Error in hist.default(dates) : 'x' must be numeric.

How do I plot my data using `hist()` specifically?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of histogram try `barplot` for character variables.

```
x <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A')
barplot(table(x))
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it using ```hist()``` specifically.

Comment: I don't think you can use `hist` to plot frequency of character variables.